# Chartjs displays numbers not time

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm trying to place time scale on the X axis.  I have tried to write a simpler and reproducible code below.  *I can get it to run fine by removing the options block but it will display the time as just superficially-meaningless numbers to the viewer*.  How do I display **time** on the X axis?  Am I missing some external source?

Note1: javascript file is a separate file, with the canvas/element "myChart" residing in the html file.

---

HTML:

```
<script src="https://www.chartjs.org/dist/2.8.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas  id="myChart" style="position: relative; width: 100%; max-height: 500px; max-width: 1000px;" ></canvas>
```

---

ERROR:
(myScript.js is the file in question)

```
Chart.min.js:7 Uncaught Error: This method is not implemented: either no adapter can be found or an incomplete integration was provided.
    at ri.oi (Chart.min.js:7)
    at i.update (Chart.min.js:7)
    at Chart.min.js:7
    at Object.each (Chart.min.js:7)
    at Object.update (Chart.min.js:7)
    at ni.updateLayout (Chart.min.js:7)
    at ni.update (Chart.min.js:7)
    at ni.construct (Chart.min.js:7)
    at new ni (Chart.min.js:7)
    at myScript.js:191
oi @ Chart.min.js:7
update @ Chart.min.js:7
(anonymous) @ Chart.min.js:7
each @ Chart.min.js:7
update @ Chart.min.js:7
updateLayout @ Chart.min.js:7
update @ Chart.min.js:7
construct @ Chart.min.js:7
ni @ Chart.min.js:7
(anonymous) @ myScript.js:191
```

---

Javascript:

```
pt1 = new Date("2019-03-15T23:36:35.316Z");
pt2 = new Date("2019-03-17T23:32:11.114Z");

var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var myBubbleChart =new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'bubble',
data: {
  datasets: [
    {
      label: ["pt1"],
      data: [{
        x: pt1,
        y: 1,
        r: 10
      }]
    }, {
      label: ["pt2"],
      data: [{
        x: pt2,
        y: 1,
        r: 10
      }]
    }
  ]
},
options: {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            type: 'time',
            distribution: 'series'
        }]
    }
}

});
```

Comment: I may have found a solution, which may entail version controls and outside sources involving chart.js and moment.js.

Answer (score 29):

It turns out, the solution entails version controls (here is what I used):

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Well, you just made my day.

Answer (score 16):

I had this same issue and attempted Kevin's solution, but it did not work. I found that it was necessary to place the moment script before the chartjs script and regardless of the versions I used, that solved the problem for me.

Comment: This is what actually helped me!

Answer (score 8):

You have to use the bundle version of Chartjs that already include Moment.js

```
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.3/dist/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using npm

```
npm install moment chartjs-adapter-moment --save-dev
```

in your files

```
import { Chart } from 'chart.js'
import 'chartjs-adapter-moment';
```

https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-adapter-moment

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error while trying to use chartkick gem for rails.
And the solution was to install `moment.js` (`npm install moment --save`) and put

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

in the `application.html.erb`